# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar que no pueda ejecutar el pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Cuando voy a ejecutar el comando `pyinstaller programa.py`

Me sale el error:

'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Ya intenté:
-Crear una variable de sistema en el path con la dirección de los scripts de python

-ejecutarlo antes con el `python3 -m`

-instarlo y desinstalo en modo administrador

Lo que eh visto es qu dentro de scripts según otro post de esta página debería estar "pyinstaller.exe" lo cual no está.

Si alguien m pudiese ayudar le agradecería es para compilar un programa como trabajo de la universidad y mi profesor no tiene tiempo para hacer monitorias y nadie me a podido ayudar

Comment: Anteriormente lo instalaste con algo similar a `python -m pip install pyinstaller`?

Comment: Sip, lo instale con ```python3 -m pip install pyinstaller``` después de desinstalarlo, lo hice así volví a revizar todo y seguía igual.

Comment: Entonces definitivamente el problema esta en la variable de entorno `PATH` y la ubicación donde se esta instalando el paquete. Al no tener mucha experiencia en windows, no te podría decir con exactitud donde puede ser que este el archivo pero lo que debes hacer es buscar el lugar donde se esta esta guardando el script `pyinstaller.exe` y agregar la ruta a tu variable de entorno `PATH`. Igualmente puedes escribir la ruta completa para ejecutar el script sin necesidad de agregarlo a la variable de entorno.